# How do you use a PC/PS3 controller when playing Skyrim on a PC?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, controllers

So I bought this PC/PS3 Controller that works for both PC and PS3. It works fine when playing Virtua Tennis 4 (on my PC), but how do I connect it to Skyrim? The only option I can see is for 360 controllers. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: The normal PS3 controller works fine with a PC:  http://www.motioninjoy.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the MotioninJoy DS3 tool, it comes with a Xbox 360 controller emulator and it works great. Just be sure to read the guide on how to install the PS3 control and enabling the emulator.

Comment: does this work on a 64 bit system because we all know 32 bit systems can run these np but i have a 64 bit system and there doesn't seem to be any software that actually work

Comment: @Gamefiend: Yes, it works fine on Windows 7 64 bit. The only drawback is that I couldn't get it to work over Bluetooth (only over USB), it seems to be picky on Bluetooth adapters. aaa: Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Xpadder works ok, but i've got noticeable lag, particularly with the R1 L1 buttons. It's only a cheap gamepad though. Got gfriends spare PS3 dualshock so trying to set that up with motionjoy on 64-bit 7.

Answer (score 1):

- Install MotioninJoy
- Open it up and click the device manager tab
- Select your device and click *load driver* - be patient as this can take a while.
- After it finished loading it will ask you to restart your computer.
- After doing the restart open up MotioninJoy again (In the profiles tab) select Xbox 360 Controller Emulator and then click enable, done!

Open Skyrim and it will automatically recognize it.

Answer (score 1):

[x360ce](http://code.google.com/p/x360ce/) will emulate an XInput (read: 360 compatible) controller with any old DirectInput (read: any other controller in existence). It is a free, open source wrapper with a minimal footprint. I use it with my PC/PS2/PS3 controller with great success.

Answer (score -1):

I use motionjoy + dualshock 3 with Xbox emulation selected.  This ran with no lag. The only thing I have not tried is using it with bluetooth.

Comment: Can you explain what exactly you did?

Answer (score -4):

It is possible that the PC version of Skyrim has no built-in system enabling it to be playable with a controller. Oh well, xpadder is one possible solution. I'm not sure if it works though.

Comment: This is not true.