# Does anyone have experience using a controller to play Skyrim on the PC?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, pc, controllers

I have Skyrim for the computer and really love playing it, but recently I've been wanting to play it while reclining in my lazyboy and playing the game on a 51in high def. My computer is right next to my amp so making the HDMI connect wouldn't be hard.

This isn't a question regarding whether or not its possible to use the controller.

My question is, for those of you who have played Skyrim with both a controller and mouse/keyboard, which one did you like better, and what were the ups and downs of each?
Would the best option be to recline with mouse and keyboard?

Comment: Welcome to the site Brent! As outlined in our [FAQ](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/faq), subjective questions like yours are considered off-topic on our site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have the [XBox Wireless Controller for Windows](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004QRKWKQ), and I much prefer the keyboard WASD experience. But I prefer it for exactly 1 reason: I'm playing a sneaky, bow-oriented character. Moving around is just as easy with the controller. Melee fighting is just as easy with the controller. But, making those long range stealth shots with the mouse is **so** much easier than with the controller.

I think if I were not so stealth+bow oriented, I'd be using the controller more. Also, the game just feels right with a controller. The menus, which seem to be a pain with keyboard and mouse are so much more natural with a controller. So I'm sticking to the keyboard, but only because of my current character's play style.

Comment: Took this answer because im playing a sneaky archer character.

Comment: I have RSI with mouse, so I use the controller for everything, then quickly swap my right hand to mouse (actually trackball) to aim sniper-style.

Answer (score 2):

**Controller pros:**

- You can recline on the couch while playing on the TV. (Which you can also do when using a keyboard, but I've never managed to control the mouse properly that way.)
- As Jarret Meyer says, the menus are faster, simpler and more natural to navigate with a controller.
- Possibly subjective, but I find it more natural to control the character with two joysticks.

**Controller cons:**

- You lose the keyboard shortcuts, e.g. switching between several sets of weapons or spells at a single key press. (Although the game pauses while you scroll through the quick-list of favorites, so it's not critical.)
- Aiming with a bow, especially at long range, is dramatically faster and more precise when using a mouse.
- *Situation dependent: I'm using a [PS3 controller](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/37013/how-do-you-use-a-pc-ps3-controller-when-playing-skyrim-on-a-pc), installation was somewhat fiddly and I couldn't get it to work over Bluetooth. So no wireless controller for me; but it works fine over USB.*

I'm using the controller for now, I prefer the more relaxed play style. But it would be hard to defend picking the controller for a sneaking-and-archery oriented character.